# Sending ASP.NET Model through AJAX

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

I'm trying to send part of a model through an ajax call, but doing it simply like my code below, doesn't work. How could I pass this object along?

```
$.ajax({
            url: "/Controller/Action",
            type: "GET",
            data: @Model.Company,
            success: function (result) {
            $('#myDiv').html(data);
        }
});
```

This is what my JS puts outs:

```
MyProj.Domain.Entities.Company
```

This is my error:

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: MyProj is not defined
```

Comment: what data type is `@Model.Company`?

Comment: Just a remark: you can use `"@Url.Action("Action", "Controller")"` instead of `"/Controller/Action"`. (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd492874(v=vs.108).aspx)

Comment: Well, still the most likely problem with your code presented here. Do you get any errors?

Comment: Could well be because the model property `company` is a class object and needs to be serialized first. Also, If you are getting something with the Ajax call based on the Company, do you need to pass everything? Would it not be enough to just pass something like: `data: {CompanyId: @Model.Company.Id}` or similar? Then all you need in your controller action is the `int CompanyId` paramter.

Comment: You can't just pass the `Model` definition because they're not exactly data that is useful to the server. You need to serialize the `Form` when the form is submitted. It's either you convert it to a `JSON` format or `Serialize` the Model object as a whole.

Answer (score 7):

Your syntax would work fine for a primitive variable, but you should serialize your object to Json before sending. And also make sure that script stays in cshtml or aspx page, else '@Html' helper will not work.

```
$.ajax({
            url: "/Controller/Action",
            type: "GET",
            data: @Html.Raw(Json.Encode(Model.Company)),
            success: function (result) {
            $('#myDiv').html(data);
        }
});
```